# Get Google access token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api-js-client

To get Google access token after firebase auth login, I know I can simply do this:

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
}
```

but what if the user is already authenticated and I need the token? is there any way to extract it from the Firebase auth?

I've been through every value of `authState` but I couldn't find the google access token I've been looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get the access token from the `onAuthStateChanged` listener or the `currentUser`. You can only get it immediately after authentication when calling `signInWithPopup`, `reauthenticateWithPopup`, `linkWithPopup`, `getRedirectResult`, etc. Firebase Auth does not manage OAuth tokens for users. If you feel strongly about this feature, please file a feature request for it on the Firebase forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

You can also just use the GApi library to get the Google access token and pass it to Firebase to sign-in via `signInWithCredential`. The advantage here is that GApi will manage that OAuth token for you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried: `let token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token;
        this.afAuth.auth
          .signInWithCredential(token)` but it says `"credential" must be a valid credential.`. Any idea what I have to pass to this method in order to authenticate?

Comment: You can't just pass a plain ID token, you have to wrap it in a credential. `signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token))`